# Find the large_files but output unexpected results

Tags: python, centos

I have such a program to find the large files

```
import os, time, shelve
start = time.time()
root = '/'
# errors= set()
# dirs = set()
while True:
    try:
        root = os.path.abspath(root) #ensure its a abspath
        #set the baseline as 100M 
        #consider the shift
        baseline = 100 * 2**20  # 2*20 is1M
        #setup to collect the large files
        large_files = []

        #root is a better choise as the a concept
        for foldername, subfolders, files in os.walk(root):
            for f in files:
                # print(f"{foldername}, {f}")
                abspath = os.path.join(foldername, f)
                size = os.path.getsize(abspath)
                if size >= baseline:
                    large_files.append((os.path.basename(abspath), size))
                    print(abspath, size/(2**20))

        #write the large files to shelf
        shelf = shelve.open('/root/large_files.db')
        shelf["large_files"] = large_files
        shelf.close()

        if subfolders == []:
            end = time.time()
            break

    except (PermissionError,FileNotFoundError) as e:
        # errors.add(e)
        pass
```

It consistently output the identical results

```
[root@iz2ze9wve43n2nyuvmsfx5z ~]# python3 search_large_files.py 
/dev/core 134217726.0078125
/dev/core 134217726.0078125
/dev/core 134217726.0078125
....
```

However, I found no reasons that

```
 print(abspath, size/(2**20))
```

will do this constantly.

What's the problem might be in my code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite outer loop with `while True:`, and apparently `/dev/core` is the only file in your filesystem that exceeds the file size specified by `baseline`, so it would keep outputting the same file over and over again.

Remove `while True:` and un-indent the block inside and your code would work.

Note that your `if subfolders == []:` condition is outside your `for foldername, subfolders, files in os.walk(root):` loop and would therefore not be useful. You should record the end time unconditionally anyway so you should simply remove the `if` condition and the `break` statement as well.

Comment: I introduced "while True" because if running it on MacOS to encounter "PermissionError", the codes will break.

Comment: I see, but all `while True:` does is to try the same thing again, which I don't think will help the permission error it gets in the first iteration. You should find the root cause of the permission error and either avoid accessing the problematic files/folders or allow the process the have the proper permission to access those files/folders.